# JSON/simple text parsing server response with Swift 4 Decodable

Tags: json, swift, parsing, codable

I'm experiencing the following troubles. By client iOS app is collaborating with the certain back-end service what send 2 types of responses: JSON on success and simple text on error.

for the JSON one I have the simple decodable struct:

```
    struct Response: Decodable {
        let message: String
    }
```

and it works till the servers sends simple text in http body and I get the following error:

> "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."

Maybe the Response struct may be more universal for such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way to make your `Decodable` struct handle such error, since in case the `Data` you are trying to decode isn't valid JSON, the `init(from decoder:)` method isn't even called, so you need to handle the error outside the scope of the initializer.

One possible solution is to handle the error in the catch block of the `JSONDecoder.decode(Response.self,from:)` method. Once the `decode` function threw an error, you can check if the error was due to incorrect input (which in this case most probably means that the input was a simple string and not JSON) and you can simply convert the response data to a `String`, then call the memberwise initializer of `Response` to initialize it with the string response.

The following example shows how to handle such case with two example responses, one being valid JSON, the other one being a simple string.

```
let validJsonResponseData = """
{"message" : "A message"}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
let simpleTextResponseData = "Error".data(using: .utf8)!

struct Response: Decodable {
    let message: String
}

do {
    let successResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: validJsonResponseData)
    let errorResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: simpleTextResponseData)
} catch {
    if let error = error as? DecodingError {
        switch error {
        case .dataCorrupted(_):
            if let simpleTextResponse = String(data: simpleTextResponseData, encoding: .utf8) {
                let errorResponse = Response(message: simpleTextResponse)
            }
        default:
            throw error
        }
    } else {
        throw error
    }
}
```